# Can I use flutter in my react native app?

Tags: react-native, redux, flutter, react-redux, realm

So I have a react native app and was hoping if I could use flutter for some  components.

We are using redux for state management and was curious if we could use the same redux store for flutter components.
And for persistence we are using realm, was curious if flutter supports realm.

Comment: No and no. Flutter had an independent redux implementation, and don't have Realm

Comment: Out of curiosity, since you have implemented Redux, any reason why you're using `realm`? Because for the persistence part we have `Redux-persist` or `redux-offline`

Comment: @Isaac so we are not using redux-offline or redux-persist because in our case the amount of data was huge an we really did'nt want to have all that in memory and secondly we had complex queries being run on the data so we needed a separate data layer for the same.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't use flutter component into react native because both are written in different technology language stack.

1. **Flutter** is an open-source mobile application framework that works on
   a completely different programming language called **Dart**, While **React
   Native** lets you build mobile apps using only **JavaScript**.

   **Dart** is based on c/c++, java and supports things like abstraction,
   encapsulation, inheritance, and polymorphism. Flutter team picked
   Dart because it matched the way they were building user interfaces,
   With Dart bridge, the application size is bigger, but it works much
   faster. Unlike React Native with **Javascript** bridge.
2. Second **Redux is an application architecture**, made originally for
       JavaScript. Redux provide library for both but we can't use same
       redux state for react native and flutter. Redux are written
       different for both platform with same functionality and
       working(state management)
3. **Realm** is also a **third party plugin** which is available for both
       platform but we can't share code between both platform.

Comment: Is realm supported by flutter ?

Comment: Currently it is not support flutter but realm developer working on it to provide realm db for flutter. Check this realm forum link  and github url    https://forum.realm.io/t/realm-for-flutter-io/171    and           https://github.com/realm/realm-object-server/issues/55

Comment: Now there is an officla package but it is still in alpha version -> https://pub.dev/packages/realm